# Theme page width editing - with slider

Tags: wordpress, layout, themes, editing

I have another question for you guys. So i'm using the Prospect theme 
http://themes.wpbusinessbundle.com/prospect/

And I don't know how to have those elements shown in the demo:

1) have the white ''writing'' space under the slider exactly the same width as the slider (I could also modify this with columns in a desperate case I guess) - now it's full page

2) keep it white! when i put writing in it, the background keeps turning pale blue, and it splits into 2: pale blue and white

Wish I could show you an example but I'm making it local, so... hope you got something out of that and can help me?

Ok, this is what i get when I try to edit the page: http://www.codrutamarin.com/?page_id=745 --- I want it to be dark blue and white, like in the original template shown above - AND for it to be centered under the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hard to understand what you mean tbh. Maybe take a print screen?

Comment: Ok, this is what i get when I try to edit the page http://codrutamarin.com/?page_id=745 --- I want it to be dark blue and white, like in the original template shown above - AND for it to be centered under the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

Woah what did you do ;P.

You should make a page with the theme template of 'Home page' on the right menu of WP. The large block of text with the large button is just called a 'call-to-action' and this can be accessed by pressing the visual editor button in the 'Visual' view of the page.

After you've published the page, Go to 'Appearance -> Themes' and then on Prospect, select Customize, then 'Static Page' and set the new home page as the static page for the front end of your site.